# CoreData and null Value

Tags: objective-c, core-data, null

Is it possible to place a null value in an entity attribute that is set to accept a string?

I have an attribute for notes that is set to receive a string but the webservice that I'm tapping brings back a value of null when the notes fields is empty.

Comment: Does setting it to an empty string work for you?

Comment: How would I set it to an empty string if the value that comes back is literally null? Not the string "null" but the value null.

Comment: Something like `if (valueFromWebService == nil) {return @"";};`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the actual web service response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the answer. The solution was to set up the conditional as follows:

```
if (NSLocalizedString([actionItem objectForKey:@"Notes"], nil) == [NSNull null]) {
    newAction.notes = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since NSDictionarys and NSArrays can't contain `nil` values, when server responses are `null` stored as the `[NSNull null]` singleton. Unfortunately that evals to `true` if you perform an if check on it since its a valid object.

Core data itself can store `nil` values for objects, but depending on if you want `nil` or an empty string is up to you.

The way we solve this at work we have a helper function in an `NSObject` category (which is imported in the .pch)

```
id ObjectOrNull(id object) {
    if (!object || object == [NSNull null]) return nil;
    return object;
}
```

And hand the response to that function either in a way like

```
coreDataInstance.data = (ObjectOrNull(response[@"key"]) ?: @"";
```

or just assign it as

```
coreDataInstance.data = (ObjectOrNull(réponse[@"key"]);
```